# Eclipseでファイル名の一部を指定して文字コードを設定したい

Tags: eclipse

設定する方法を教えて下さい。
指定したいファイル名以外はUTF-8なのですが、フィーチャーフォン用のxhtmlだけはShift-JISに設定したいです。

こんな感じです

- 「`*Hoge*.xhtml`」は「Shift-JIS」
- その他の「*.xhtml」は「UTF-8」
- 「.xhtml」以外のファイルも「UTF-8」

ワークスペースやプロジェクト全体に「UTF-8」を設定して「`*Hoge*.xhtml`」だけ除外し、「Shift-JIS」を設定する 
という方法でも構いません(やれるかどうかもわからない状態です)。

拡張子だけであれば設定のコンテンツ・タイプで設定できることはわかりました。 
[Eclipseで文字コードと改行コードを設定する方法](http://qiita.com/ponsuke0531/items/74833b2d7bd4bbf44057)

- 環境

  - Eclipse : Kepler Service Release 2 Build id: 20140224-0627
  - OS : Windows7

Answer (score 0):

ファイルを右クリックし、ファイルごとのプロパティを使えば、ファイルごとに文字コードを変えることができます。
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

一番多い文字コードを全体設定し、残りは個別にこの画面で設定するのはどうでしょうか？

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。実はstackoverflowのMarkdownがよくわかっていなくて質問文のHoge.xhtmlは`*Hoge*.xhtml`と書きたかったのです。「Hoge」を含むxhtmlファイルは複数存在し、増える可能性もあるのです。プロジェクトチームで文字コードを設定したいので`*Hoge*.xhtml`を設定したいと考えています。その方法はありますでしょうか？

Comment: 文字コードを混在させるメリットに興味があります。教えていただけますか？